# Using MS Graph API to subscribe/import an iCal URL

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

How can I use the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) to import/subscribe an Office365 user to a calendar hosted at a URL in iCal format? For example, suppose I have a calendar hosted at https://example.org/events.ical and I want this calendar to appear in a user's Outlook hosted on Office365?

If I were doing it manually I'd follow [these instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-subscribe-to-a-calendar-in-outlook-on-the-web-503ffaf6-7b86-44fe-8dd6-8099d95f38df). But I can't find a Graph API for doing it.

Doing the AzureAD auth/permissions/token isn't an issue, I have that all working. It's just which API to call for Outlook on Office365.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't a supported method. You would need to parse the events from the iCal feed in your app and then use Graph to create the actual events.